# How to restore behaviour of file save dialog?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I stop apps from selecting “Recently Used” by default in file chooser dialogs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63202/can-i-stop-apps-from-selecting-recently-used-by-default-in-file-chooser-dialog)

There's something I find really annoying about a recent change to Gnome3 and/or GTK+.

Often I code on three or more different projects in a single day and then I might go to my web browser, find a PDF file and decide to save it. The problem is that the file save dialog box now shows a whole bunch of suggested places to save the file, with all the directories I'm coding in at the top of the list.

This is borked. Is there some way to restore more sane behaviour?

Comment: ... and this is a similar question how this was solved for Evince - http://askubuntu.com/questions/76514/how-do-i-make-nautilus-to-automatically-suggest-the-folder-documents-for-pdf-f/79644#79644

Comment: @fossfreedom that was not helpful. I asked a general question with a example saving a PDF file and you gave an answer that was specific to evince. Furthermore, suggesting that everybody that doesn't like this current behavior in Evince recompile Evince is insane! So how do I fix Evince, Gedit, Gimp, and every other program I use?

Comment: .. what i was trying to say (probably badly) - is that individual apps need to be recoded (like the evince example).  See the suggested duplicate for more info.  Unfortunately the gnome-devs seem to like this design :(

Comment: In any one week I probably use 50+ different Gnome/Gtk apps. Hacking the sources of every single app is simply not going to happen.

Comment: I share your frustration ... however, according to the suggested duplicate, there is not much ubuntu can do about this - upstream decided that this design is the "future"