# Can 'Save as' in Atril be configured to open the file chooser with most recent directory selected instead of /home/Documents for downloaded PDFs?

Tags: pdf, gtk, evince

For downloaded PDF files opened in Atril, the 'Save as' file chooser dialogue defaults to the /home/Documents directory, which is not what I want to use 100% of the time. Ideally I would like to be able to specify the default directory (/home/Downloads in my case), but would also be happy if the last used directory was the default.

The same problem has been described in [Can evince be configured to suggest last used folder when using "save as" from a downloaded document?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154376), but for Ubuntu 20.04 there still does not seem to be a resolution. Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Also, the solution offered in answer to [Can evince be configured to suggest last used folder when using "save as" from a downloaded document?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154376) no longer works with Ubuntu 20.04 (the PPA linked to in the answer has not been recently updated). Also, I would rather keep using Atril without having to install / switching to Xreader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only solution to this problem is a modified source and recompiled application. I have created a version with an additional command line parameter (--documents-dir) that enables the user to specify the default save as directory. For details, see [this post](https://blog.laczik.org/atril-evince-document-viewer-default-directory-for-save-as/).

I have also created binary packages for 20.04, which are available from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elaczik/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:laczik/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt upgrade atril
```